# Insert newline character at index in .bash

Tags: json, bash

I'm taking an introductory course to bash at my university and am working on a little MotD script that uses a json-object grabbed from an API using curl.

I want to make absolutely certain that you understand that this is **NOT** an assignment, but something I'm playing around with to learn more about how to script with bash.

I've found myself stuck with what could possibly be a very simply issue; I want to insert a new line ('`\n`') on a specific index if the 'quote' value of my json-object is too long (in this case on index 80).

I've been following a bunch of SO threads and this is my current solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

json_object=$(curl -s 'http://quotes.stormconsultancy.co.uk/random.json')
quote=$(echo ${json_object} | jq .quote | sed -e 's/^"//' -e 's/"$//')
author=$(echo ${json_object} | jq .author)
count=${#quote}
echo $quote
echo $author
echo "wc: $count"


if((count > 80));
then
        quote=${quote:0:80}\n${quote:80:(count - 80)}
else
        echo "lower"
fi
printf "$quote"
```

The current output I receive from the `printf` is the first word of the quote, whereas if I have an `echo` before trying to do the string-manipulation I get the entire quote.

I'm sorry if it's not following best practice or anything, but I'm an absolute beginner using both `vi` and `bash`.

I'd be very happy with any sort of advice. :)

**EDIT:**

Sample output:

> $ ./json.bash
>
> You should name a variable using the same care with which you name a first-born child.
>
> "James O. Coplien"
>
> 86
>
> higher
>
> You should name a variable using the same care with which you name a first-born nchild.

Comment: you need to provide a sample output of all those variables, how else do you expect to solve the problem for you. first and foremost the `JSON` output. Explain with proper data on each step why are you doing this and what you expected it do.

Comment: ...also it is a good practice to double-quote all variables in `bash`

Comment: Added a sample output.

Using double on variables regardless of context? Like in the `if`?

Comment: Changed it to "$quote". As you can see it prints the whole string, with no real change...

Comment: As mentioned I basically want to insert a newline character on index 80 if the string is longer than 80 characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use a single line `bash` command to achieve this,

```
string="You should name a variable using the same care with which you name a first-born child."
(( "${#string}" > 80 )) && printf "%s\n" "${string:0:80}"$'\n'"${string:80}" || printf "%s\n" "$string"
You should name a variable using the same care with which you name a first-born 
child.
```

(and) for an input line less than `80` charaacters

```
string="You should name a variable using the same care"
(( "${#string}" > 80 )) && printf "%s\n" "${string:0:80}"$'\n'"${string:80}" || printf "%s\n" "$string"
You should name a variable using the same care
```

An explanation,

```
(( "${#string}" > 80 )) && printf "%s\n" "${string:0:80}"$'\n'"${string:80}" || printf "%s\n" "$string"

# The syntax is a indirect implementation of ternary operator as bash doesn't 
# directly support it.
#
# (( "${#string}" > 80 )) will return a success/fail depending upon the length
# of the string variable and if it is greater than 80, the command after && is
# executed and if it fails the command after || is executed
#
# "${string:0:80}"$'\n'"${string:80}"
# A parameter expansion syntax for sub-string extraction.
#
# ${PARAMETER:OFFSET}
#
# ${PARAMETER:OFFSET:LENGTH}
#
# This one can expand only a part of a parameter's value, given a position 
# to start and maybe a length. If LENGTH is omitted, the parameter will be 
# expanded up to the end of the string. If LENGTH is negative, it's taken as
# a second offset into the string, counting from the end of the string.
#
# So in our example we basically extract the characters from position 0 to 80
# insert a new-line and append the rest of the string 
#
# The $'\n' syntax allows to include all escape sequence characters be 
# included, in this case just the new line character.
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Would you mind adding some explanation of what's going on in the solution(s)?

Comment: @geostocker: adding it now. Is this what you intended to do?

Answer (score 0):

Not really in the original question, but adding some extra code to @Inian great answer to allow not to break in the middle of a word, but rather at the last white space in `${string:0:80}`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

string="You should really name a variable using the same care with which you name a first-born child."
if (( "${#string}" > 80 )); then
    maxstring="${string:0:80}"
    lastspace="${maxstring##*\ }"
    breakat="$((${#maxstring} - ${#lastspace}))"
    printf "%s\n" $"${string:0:${breakat}}"$'\n'"${string:${breakat}}"
else
    printf "%s\n" "$string"
fi
```

**`maxstring=${string:0:80}`:**

Let's get the first 80 characters of the quote.

**`lastspace=${maxstring##*\ }`:**

Deletes longest match of `*\` (white space is escaped) from front of `$maxstring`, `${lastspace}` will be the remaining string from last white space until end of the string.

**`breakat="$((${#maxstring} - ${#lastspace}))"`:**

Subtract the length of `${lastspace}` with the length of `${maxstring}` to get the last index of the white space from `${maxstring}`. This is the index where `\n` will be inserted.

Example output with "hard" break at character 80:

```
You should really name a variable using the same care with which you name a firs
t-born child.
```

Example output with a "soft" break at the closest white space from character 80:

```
You should really name a variable using the same care with which you name a 
first-born child.
```